# Add break condition when looping through dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary that looks like this: `{'1132': '16', '1133': '1', '1141': '1', '1142': '32', '1143': '1'}`. What I want is to implement an if-else condition with break and continue.

```
 for key, value in area_dict.items():
    ndic = math.ceil((value * difference_new_old_mass) / freq_sum)
    l[key] = ndic
```

Basically, I want when the values in the dict reach a target to break.
'l' is an empty dictionary. I want to add the following code somewhere in the math.ceil function, but don't know how: summ should be the list 'l', this is just an example

```
summ = []
for k, v in l.items():
     summ[k] = sum(v)
     if summ == difference_new_old_mass:
            break
     else:
            continue
```

Another problem that i have is the second code gives me `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` and can't figure out what is causing that.

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to figure out the problem, but regarding the `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, the dictionary values are integers and thus, `v` contains an integer value, so you can't do `sum(v)`.

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem if they are integers? They need to be strings? I want to sum the values..

Comment: The problem is it is an integer, not integers!

Comment: May be give an example and expected result to help me understand what exactly you want to do?

Comment: All I want is to write a loop that makes this calculation `math.ceil((value * difference_new_old_mass) / freq_sum)` for every value in the dict and to stop  until the sum of the values in this dict reach a certain value.